# How to enable the SD card to be written on by all apps [Mrashmallow]

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card

Is there any way without rooting the device? My device is a Sony Xperia C4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use adaptable storage to do this. This means that your SD card with merge with your internal storage and display itself as one big SD card. This is really nice if you need extra storage, but things can go crazy if you pull your SD card out of your phone as it's used as internal storage.

Just make sure NOT to pull out your SD card from your phone if you decide to enable this.

You can enable it in 2 ways:

**ADB**:

```
adb shell sm set-force-adoptable true
```

**From Settings**

Go to Settings -> Storage -> SD Card -> Format as internal

Comment: I don't see that option in the settings. Would either of these actions delete the files already on the SD card?

Comment: @Reza Yes, all contents will be deleted off the SD card.

Comment: @Reza Some OEM's remove the Adopted Storage options from the user interface for Marshmallow, but using the ADB method works in most cases. It would be a good idea to update your original question with your make/model of device as that can change the answer.

Comment: I enabled debugging and ran the command but I get an error that sm was not found. I don't know how to install it in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Reza I don't know, sorry. I have the option in my settings. I just found this command on the internet. Installing Busybox might solve it. (Busybox installer is free on Google Play)